# Upload form reading from sys.stdin works for txt and pdf, not for jpg – what is wrong?

Tags: python, forms, post, sys

This script uses sys.stdin for uploading files as an exercise, it works for .txt and .pdf files, but not for e. g. jpgs that get truncated. Can this be done simpler and safe for all file types? E. g. extracting 'filename' and 'Content-Type' via regex certainly isn't ideal. My shared hoster doesn't support modules like requests or werkzeug out of the box, so I'd like to have a simple solution.

[image: screenshot]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys, re
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("\n\n")
tmpl = \
"""
<html>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    action="/tools/py.py" method="post">
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
"""

def escape(data):
    data    = bytes(data[4], "utf-8")
    return    data.decode("unicode_escape")

def write_buf():
    if sys.stdin:
        buf     = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
        data    = str(buf).split("\\r\\n")

        if buf:
            print(data[1] + "<hr>\n")
            print(data[2] + "<hr>\n")

            rx              = '\Wname=\"([^\"]+)\"'
            name            = re.search(rx, data[1]).group(1)

            rx              = '\Wfilename=\"([^\"]+)\"'
            file_name       = re.search(rx, data[1]).group(1)

            rx              = '^Content-Type: (.+)$'
            content_type    = re.search(rx, data[2]).group(1)

            with open('bu/' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
                if content_type == 'text/plain':
                    f.write(escape(data).encode())
                else: # (e. g. 'application/pdf')
                    f.write(buf)

print(tmpl)
write_buf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out myself. This works for all file types, though only for single uploads:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os, sys, re, html
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print("\n\n")
tmpl = \
"""
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
<body>
   <form enctype="multipart/form-data"
                    action="/tools/upload.py" method="post">
   <p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>
   <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
"""

def write_buf():
    if sys.stdin:
        buf = sys.stdin.buffer.read()

        if buf:
            rgx         = rb'\Wfilename=\"([^\"]+)\"'
            file_name   = re.search(rgx, buf).group(1)
            #file_name   = file_name.decode("unicode_escape")
            file_name   = file_name.decode()

            rgx         = rb'(-{29}\d{29})'
            boundary    = re.search(rgx, buf).group(1)
            boundary    = boundary.decode()

            rgx         = rb"-{29}\d{29}"
            lst_data    = re.split(rgx, buf)

            rgx         = rb"Content-Type: \w+/[\w-]+\r\n\r\n"
            lst_data    = re.split(rgx, lst_data[1])
            data        = lst_data[1]

            print("file_name: " + file_name + "<hr>\n")
            print("boundary: "  + boundary  + "<hr>\n")

            for el in lst_data:
                strng   = html.escape(str(el))
                print("data: <code>" + strng + "</code><hr>\n")

            with open('bu/' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(data)

print(tmpl)
write_buf()
``
```